# The fastest C++ algorithm for string testing against a list of predefined seeds (case insensitive)

Tags: c++, string, windows, algorithm

I have list of seed strings, about 100 predefined strings. All strings contain only ASCII characters.

```
std::list<std::wstring> seeds{ L"google", L"yahoo", L"stackoverflow"};
```

My app constantly receives a lot of strings which can contain any characters. I need check each received line and decide whether it contain any of seeds or not. Comparison must be case insensitive.

I need the fastest possible algorithm to test received string.

Right now my app uses this algo:

```
std::wstring testedStr;
for (auto & seed : seeds)
{
    if (boost::icontains(testedStr, seed))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

It works well, but I'm not sure that this is the most efficient way.

How is it possible to implement the algorithm in order to achieve better performance?

This is a Windows app. App receives valid `std::wstring` strings.

---

**Update**

For this task I implemented Aho-Corasick algo. If someone could review my code it would be great - I do not have big experience with such algorithms. Link to implementation: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Mezrin/07a5495e2cbb72bf5e68b3257b38b7ba)

Comment: As a tiny improvement I'd suggest to replace `std::list` with an array (normal array, `std::array` or `std::vector`). It may improve performance a bit. Also, why do you have `L` prefix only on one of the literals?

Comment: they contain a seed or they are a seed? there's a difference

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am sorry for all that typos )) I placed L before other two literals.

Comment: @DavidHaim I have a list of seeds, I need check whether received string contain "google" or not.

Comment: @dyp Case insensitive. Sorry for typo ))

Comment: have you tried `std::search` and found out it's not fast enough?

Comment: @DavidHaim I need case insensitive search. std::search do case sensitive search. Therefore in the current version of algo boost::icontains used

Comment: hmmm.. so simply use `tolower` on each string. or put a specifi comparator if its ascii only it shouldn't take a lot of time anyway. my point is to try to milk the standard library as much as possible, it is very fast

Comment: Hm. What's more likely: The line does contain a seed or it doesn't? Are all of the seeds equally likely to appear?

Comment: Is the list of seeds known at compile time, or is it known only at runtime?

Comment: Worth noting: you most likely do *not* need the fastest algorithm.  We often pay for the "fastest" algorithm in blood and tears, when "fast" would have been sufficient.  The "fastest" algorithm would have to include things like managing the cache on your particular CPU, and how fast different opcodes run, and be custom tailored to the specific set of words you are looking at, and the relative probabilities of the words occuring.  Those details are a pain.  Use the "fast" algorithms below =)

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum lengths of the seeds?

Comment: @CortAmmon: A good point; even better would be if Victor can determine actual performance targets, or some metric of how much he gains by achieving a given speed-up. Then, if an easy solution is not good enough, he could look for benchmarks of other algorithms, and try to to take into account the other questions here like how long and probable the seeds are; a complexity class on its own does not give the answer. But, since he has already implemented Aho-Corasick, it is probably too late to worry!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm)

It builds trie/automaton where some vertices marked as terminal which would mean string has seeds.

It's built in `O(sum of dictionary word lengths)` and gives the answer in  `O(test string length)`

Advantages:

- It's specifically works with several dictionary words and check time doesn't depend on number of words (If we not consider cases where it doesn't fit to memory etc)
- The algorithm is not hard to implement (comparing to suffix structures at least)

You may make it case insensitive by lowering each symbol if it's ASCII (non ASCII chars don't match anyway)

Comment: Yes, probably the fastest possible way. AFAIK, this is used in antivirus software to test files for virus signatures.

Comment: What about cache performance? I am not sure how much good tries -- in general trees -- in terms of cache locality.

Comment: @RiaD Thank you for the help! I implemented AhoCorasick on C++. It works well and fast )) https://gist.github.com/Mezrin/07a5495e2cbb72bf5e68b3257b38b7ba. If you could review the code it would be great ))

Answer (score 57):

If there are a finite amount of matching strings, this means that you can construct a tree such that, read from root to leaves, similar strings will occupy similar branches.

This is also known as a [**trie**, or Radix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree).

For example, we might have the strings `cat, coach, con, conch` as well as `dark, dad, dank, do`. Their trie might look like this:

[image]

A search for one of the words in the tree will search the tree, starting from a root. Making it to a leaf would correspond to a match to a seed. Regardless, each character in the string should match to one of their children. If it does not, you can terminate the search (e.g. you would not consider any words starting with "g" or any words beginning with "cu").

There are various algorithms for constructing the tree as well as searching it as well as modifying it on the fly, but I thought I would give a conceptual overview of the solution instead of a specific one since I don't know of the best algorithm for it.

Conceptually, an algorithm you might use to search the tree would be related to the idea behind *radix sort* of a fixed amount of categories or values that a character in a string might take on at a given point in time.

This lets you check one word against your [word-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_(data_structure)).  Since you're looking for this word-list as sub-strings of your input string, there's going to be more to it than this.

**Edit:** As other answers have mentioned, the Aho-Corasick algorithm for string matching is a sophisticated algorithm for performing string matching, consisting of a trie with additional links for taking "shortcuts" through the tree and having a different search pattern to accompany this. (As an interesting note, Alfred Aho is also a contributor to the the popular compiler textbook, *Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools* as well as the algorithms textbook, *The Design And Analysis Of Computer Algorithms*. He is also a former member of Bell Labs. Margaret J. Corasick does not seem to have too much public information on herself.)

Comment: Best answer to me :) it shows partially how to implement a Regex, wich is what the OP needs in the end (though he don't need the whol regex capabilities)

Comment: Since the OP wants to find these words as substrings of a longer (multi-word?) string, I'm not sure that looping over each possible start-character or word will work as efficiently as other options.  (In real life, SIMD vectors are a big deal for stuff like this.)  Although as @DarioOO says, probably constructing a regex that matches any of the words, and feeding that to a regex library only when it changes, will give fast pattern matching with an algorithm like this.

Comment: @PeterCordes We can improve slightly the algorithm by replacing the character looping with a direct jump (sort of quick character hash). Probably some regex library already do that.

Comment: Unclear whether this is the best solution: there are two issues here (1) no mention of the theoretical complexity for checking *containment* (not just match) and (2) the scattered nature of the reads is not cache friendly.

Comment: I didn't realize this at first but @MatthieuM. is exactly correct. Your algorithm takes quadratic time in the worst case since you have to try it for all prefixes.

Comment: Aho-Corasick is a trie with internal links that allow you to not have to re-search from the root at every position in your string. In my experience it is significantly faster (1.5x) than a naive trie with a large number of seach strings.

Comment: @DarioOO Regex is a bad solution to the problem the OP stated.

Answer (score 16):

You should try a pre-existing regex utility, it may be slower than your hand-rolled algorithm but regex is about matching multiple possibilities, so it is likely it will be already several times faster than a hashmap or a simple comparison to all strings. I believe regex implementations may already use the  Aho–Corasick algorithm mentioned by RiaD, so basically you will have at your disposal a well tested and fast implementation.

If you have C++11 you already have a standard regex library

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(){
     std::regex self_regex("google|yahoo|stackoverflow");
     regex_match(input_string ,self_regex);
}
```

I expect this to generate the best possible minimum match tree, so I expect it to be really fast (and reliable!)

Comment: At least the regex implementations I know perform poorly if you have multiple candidates with the same (long) prefix and the string is one of the last or isn't in the dictionary at all. For common regex implementation the runtime will be between O(N) and O(N^2) because of this depending on the seed.

Comment: While different implementation of C++ library can include support for such use case, there is no guarantee in the specs. If the use case is purely for searching fixed list of words, and efficiency is of utmost importance, then it's better to use a library implementing Aho-Corasick algorithm directly, instead of relying on a possible optimization in regex engine which may not even be implemented.

Comment: I do not expect standard library use common implementations, what I expect is they use the best possible algorithms and their support become better in the time, of course since OP wants performance he will do profiling and test out various solutions. If  `<regex>` yields a good performance to me is the best choice since it can scale better in future (simple to add more words or even new rules for matching words). I used in few places the standard regex and it is already faster than many hand-made libraries. The committee never mandates "explicitly the algorithms", but impose many constraints.

Comment: The Rust `regex` library uses Aho-Corasick (as well as many other tricks), but I am not sure that the C++ implementations do. Still, this answer has the merit of being *simple* and let's face it the OP is starting from lists anyway...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Then the OP should just code that one particular piece in Rust.

Comment: @H.Idden: when generating the regex from the list of words, factor out the prefixes with a sort + some heuristics into `pre\(text|fix|posterous\)`.  It should be easy to implement that, or even find a regex-optimizer library that can do that and more.  But good point that some regex implementations support so many features that they don't use optimal algorithms for simple regexes.

Comment: Regex is probably a sub optimal solution to this problem.  It isn't bad for a *prototype*, but the OP asked for "fastest", and regex is very rarely that *unless* you hit a case that this particular regex library has massively optimized.  A runtime regex library has to compile the regex expression, which will take some time, and also won't qualify as "fastest".  I will state that your first pass *should* be to use `std::regex`, and determine if that is fast enough, and use it to check correctness and compare speeds with your hand-crafted optimizations if you need to.

Answer (score 10):

One of the faster ways is to use suffix tree https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree, but this approach has huge disadvantage - it is difficult data structure with difficult constructing. This algorithm allows to build tree from string in linear complexity https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm

Comment: The only answer that address performance and his requirements. find any substring against a list of strings. that is what search engines do!

Answer (score 6):

Edit: As  Matthieu M. pointed out, the OP asked if a string contains a keyword. My answer only works when the string equals the keyword or if you can split the string e.g. by the space character.

Especially with a high number of possible candidates and knowing them at compile time using a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) with a tool like gperf is worth a try. The main principle is, that you seed a generator with your seed and it generates a function that contains a hash function which has no collisions for all seed values. At runtime you give the function a string and it calculates the hash and then it checks if it is the only possible candidate corresponding to the hashvalue.

The runtime cost is hashing the string and then comparing against the only possible candidate (O(1) for seed size and O(1) for string length).

To make the comparison case insensitive you just use tolower on the seed and on your string.

Comment: Note that a Perfect Hash usually supposes that the input be part of the pre-determined seeds, which is not the case here. As a result, there may be collisions between the hashes of non-seeds and seeds. Oh, and this only works for full matches, not *containment*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You are right. I didn't read the word "contains" carefully enough because I was misleaded by the headline. gperf already handles non-seeds internally (most likely by comparing the string against the only possible seed.

Comment: Well, not much is lost if you replace "perfect" with "rolling". Then you have Rabin-Karp, which performs well. I'm not sure how it compares to Aho-Corasick, never having used the latter. Formally, AC is faster, but that doesn't mean a lot. It's also hugely more complex with lots of cache-unfriendly operations. I would bet my money or Rabin-Karp.

Comment: A perfect rolling hash should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Because number of string is not big (~100), you can use next algo:

1. Calculate max length of word you have. Let it be N.
2. Create `int checks[N];` array of checksum.
3. Let's checksum will be sum of all characters in searching phrase. So, you can calculate such checksum for each word from your list (that is known at compile time), and create `std::map<int, std::vector<std::wstring>>`, where `int` is checksum of string, and vector should contain all your strings with that checksum.
   Create array of such maps for each length (up to N), it can be done at compile time also.
4. Now move over big string by pointer. When pointer points to X character, you should add value of X char to all `checks` integers, and for each of them (numbers from 1 to N) remove value of (X-K) character, where K is number of integer in `checks` array. So, you will always have correct checksum for all length stored in `checks` array.
   After that search on map does there exists strings with such pair (length & checksum), and if exists - compare it.

It should give false-positive result (when checksum & length is equal, but phrase is not) very rare.

So, let's say R is length of big string. Then looping over it will take O(R).
Each step you will perform N operations with "+" small number (char value), N operations with "-" small number (char value), that is very fast. Each step you will have to search for counter in `checks` array, and that is O(1), because it's one memory block.

Also each step you will have to find map in map's array, that will also be O(1), because it's also is one memory block.
And inside map you will have to search for string with correct checksum for log(F), where F is size of map, and it will usually contain no more then 2-3 strings, so we can in general pretend that it is also O(1).

Also you can check, and if there is no strings with same checksum (that should happens with high chance with just 100 words), you can discard map at all, storing pairs  instead of map.

So, finally that should give O(R), with quite small O.
This way of calculating `checksum` can be changed, but it's quite simple and completely fast, with really rare false-positive reactions.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I don't think it will do well with many different lengths of search strings.  Maybe with a single 6-char sliding window or something to find candidate prefixes for all strings of length 6 or longer?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Why 6? It's an interesting concept, certainly, though I wonder that the influence of the length is. I would maybe try to use the minimum length of the seeds (is that how you derived 6?).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Pure guesswork, but yes, based on the length of the seeds.  If the min seed length is longer than 6, absolutely use that.  I thought 5 or 4 might give too many false-positives that result in a `memcmp`.  If we need to match short strings, maybe a separate sliding window for short strings, so buckets are more likely to be empty?  Or just handle short strings with a completely different strategy, like traditional regex-style pattern-matching.  The sliding window for longer strings would keep the pattern simple.

Comment: As O(N*M), where `N` is length and `M` is string count, this won't scale well.  I think we could pull off a log-speedup with a bit of divide and conquor?  Where we only have to calculate a value exactly if earlier filters fail.

Comment: @PeterCordes Idea with one sliding window is really cool to reduce O(N * M) to O(M). But because each sliding window calculation performs nearly immediately (moving pointer, +/- small number), and number of phrases is ~100, we can count O(N * M) as O(M) with quite small constant before, even with variety number of windows, anyway Victor can easily try both and compare on his data.

Answer (score 3):

As a variant on DarioOO’s answer, you could get a possibly faster implementation of a regular expression match, by coding a [lex parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) for your strings. Though normally used together with [yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc), this is a case where lex on its own does the job, and lex parsers are usually very efficient.

This approach might fall down if all your strings are long, as then an algorithm such as [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), [Commentz-Walter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commentz-Walter_algorithm) or [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) would probably offer significant improvements, and I doubt that lex implementations use any such algorithm.

This approach is harder if you have to be able to configure the strings without reconfiguration, but since [flex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_%28lexical_analyser_generator%29) is open source you could cannibalise its code.